# Unexpected 301 Redirect with Laravel, Vue, Axios and Nginx with different url same call

Tags: php, laravel, axios

Sorry if the title doesn't make sense. I will elaborate more here.

Background. This works on my local using valet but not on Ubuntu 18.04 Production. I am using Larvavel 6.18.7 and nginx verison 1.17.3 and have redirects using Certbot for http to https.
I thought it was an all round issue with the platform but have got it down to an issue with just a route to `Route::post('/business', 'BusinessController@store');`

I have been debugging for hours so I have now created some test pages to hopefully explain this better.
I have now have two Axios POST calls in a Vue Component but its actually just the business one.

```
axios.post('/business', {'q':"hello"})
.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
});

axios.post('/test', {'q':"hello"})
.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
});
```

The issue I am experiencing is the `/business` route when this is called I get a 301 Redirect. Laravel doesn't like the trailing / so thats why it is 403 but it shouldn't be redirected. 
[image: HTTP Calls]

Both these go to the same place, i have placed these at the top of my routes to check that the business isn't called anywhere else:

```
Route::post('/test', 'BusinessController@store');
Route::post('/business', 'BusinessController@store');
```

The calls are exactly the same, they go to the same location but the `/business` has a redirect.

I've tried clearing the route cache. There's no further information in my logs. I've seen

Comment: Is the business call done via https? Or first http, then bot does redirect?

Comment: Both are done with https `Request URL: https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/test` and `Request URL: https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/business`

Comment: I can imagine you have more routes. Are you sure none of the other routes could be reached using the business extension? Sometimes people experience issues with routes with similar names, and the wrong one gets chosen by laravel.

Comment: @RobBiermann Here is my route list. I commented everything out apart from the Laravel Routes and the two in question [Routes](https://imgur.com/a/Y6fFRVs)

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm, it still has the issue now that everything is commented out?

Comment: And another question: Do you have a folder/file in your public folder called business?

Comment: @RobBiermann unfortunately yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211730/discussion-between-rob-biermann-and-rbaskam).

Comment: @RobBiermann you absolute star. Yes there is a folder called business. Renamed it and it works. Thank you so much. Can you put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using routes, you need to make sure the name does not overlap with the content/structure of your public folder. If there is an overlap, the .htaccess file will just try to access the file in stead. Because the file is a folder, it tries to load it as an ftp page(301), but can't because it is disabled for security reasons(403).